# Input inside a loop

Tags: javascript

So for my JavaScript homework, I have to make a game where the user has 5 tries to guess a number between 1-10. My main problem is that everytime I try to run this (uncompleted), it only asks me for an input once. Apparently I can't put input inside a loop? I tried this with for as well. Any ideas?

```
var ans = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1
    var tries = 6
    while(tries > 0)
      {
       var guess = prompt("")
       tries--
      }
console.log("Better luck next time")
```

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: @Oriol https://xkcd.com/583/

Comment: I see other issues, like you never actually use guess to see if they got the right answer. But the prompt actually works as advertised. See: https://repl.it/DcJo

Comment: @Oriol What do you mean? I know this thing is unfinished. I pretty much have a clear idea of how to do this. My only current issue is how to make it so that the user gets asked for his guess 5 times.

Comment: where you used guess and just print tries you will came to know whether loop work correctly or not

Comment: @P1xt, I know it's unfinished. I needed to figure out how to get the input to ask 5 times. Weird how it worked on your link. Didn't work for me.

Comment: omitting semicolons is possible yet usually not a good idea imho.

Comment: @AlessandroC I mean that when I run your code, I get asked for input in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to loop through just fine here...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xr2rx7v/)

```
var ans = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
var tries = 6
while(tries > 0)
{
    var guess = prompt("")
    tries--
}
console.log("Better luck next time")
```

Comment: where is difference in question and you answer

Comment: There isn't - I was pointing out the the original poster's code already works as he or she requested. The OP is stating that it only asks for an input once - the Fiddle shows otherwise. If there's an issue, it's not in the code the OP posted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13712701)

Comment: @DanCornilescu to quote op `My main problem is that everytime I try to run this (uncompleted), it only asks me for an input once,` It seems that [mike is technically correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuPOW20diuY&t=1096). Also your link to `Users with less than 50 reputation points cannot write comments on questions and answers that they don't own.` do not seem to fit. Since OP owns the question and Mike owns the answer.

Comment: That's just an auto-filled comment from a review action. And I chose that action simply because IMHO "you don't have a problem" doesn't really answer a "my problem is..." question. Yes, it may be subjective, but that's why the review process is based on votes from multiple reviewers. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

try with for loop

```html
var ans = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1
    
    for(var tries=5; tries > 0 ;tries--)
      {
       var guess = prompt("")
       alert("user enter input 5 times");
      }
console.log("Better luck next time")
```

Comment: This behaves like OP's `while` loop. `for` won't magically fix the (non-existing) problem.

Comment: @Oriol yeah exactly but may OP's browser does not support it

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem in your code it works Fine!! Just try to use it in another browser. if your browser have problem just reset your browser. This is Solution code of your problem .and Don't worry Your Code works well on My browser .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var ans = 2//Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1
                var tries = 6
                while(tries > 0)
                  {
                   var guess = prompt("")
                   if(guess == ans){
                        console.log("You Win");
                        break
                   }
                   tries--
                   if(tries==0){
                        console.log("Better luck next time")    
                   }
                  }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```